# axios post does not send data properly

Tags: express, axios

I make a http post with axios with the code below:

```
axios.post('http://myURL.com',{name:'abc'},config).then((response)=>{
      console.log(response);
    })
```

I expect the request body to be an object like this: {name:'abc'} but my request body turn out to be {'{name:abc}':' '}

Is there something that I can do to specify that my request body is an object, not a string? Thank you!

Comment: Can I see the content of `config`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a comma is missing between url and parameters object.

```
'http://myURL.com'{name:'abc'}

// fixed
'http://myURL.com', {name:'abc'}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for pointing it out! I actually have it in my original code so I do not think it fixes the problem